# Probability of the size of a union of k sets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(A_i)_i$ be a collection of $k \geq 2$ i.i.d. random sets of sizes $S_i := |A_i| \sim p$, with $p$ a known probability distribution (i.e. we know $P(S_i = s) = p_s$ for all $s$). By independence, we have that $P(S_1 = s_1, \dots, S_k = s_k) = \prod_j^k p_{s_j}$.

What is the probability distribution of size of the **union** $A = \cup_{i=1}^k A_i$? In other words, how can I express
$$ P( S = s ) = P( |\cup_{i=1}^k A_i | = s) $$
in terms of the $p_{s_j}$?

**EDIT:** Based on [@mike-earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/177399/mike-earnest) answer, I realized that my question is ill-posed because there were many ways to sample elements from the set of positive integers. I provide further details below that may help answer the original question.

We can assume that every set $A_i$ (of respective size $s_i$) sample elements of the universal set, $U = \{1, ..., M\}$, uniformly at random without repetition. Given this extra information, can we express $P(S = s)$?

---

I've tried expanding the union using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but it didn't simplify the problem.

I tried assuming (as a first simplifying exercise) that the all intersections are empty (i.e. $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$) and compute the probability of all the $s+1 \choose k-1$ ways in which $k$ nonnegative numbers can sum up to $s$, but I didn't get to anywhere useful.

I tried building on the ideas from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115181/probability-distribution-of-size-of-union-of-two-sets), with no success, where they compute the probability of the size of the union of two **uniformly sampled** sets of given sizes.

Many thanks in advance for any answers you can provide :).

Comment: With your edit, the problem is now well defined, but I personally do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks still, @MikeEarnest. Your insight helped me a lot to state the problem properly.